# pydub.AudioSegment.from_file not finding file

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pydub, audiosegment

Hi I am trying to use Google Web Speech API for Speech Recognition, I want to convert a audio file to text. I have been able to compile this code on my raspberry pi 4 but when I compile it on my Windows computer I get an error of file not found.

Here is the error:

```
File "C:/Users/pc/Desktop/py_scripts/omg.py", line 15, in <module>
    sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file('sample.mp3')
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 651, in from_file
    file, close_file = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(file, 'rb', tempfile=False)
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 60, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.mp3'
```

And here is the code I been using:

```
import ffmpy, urllib, pydub

sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file('sample.mp3')    
sound.export('sample.wav', format="wav")
sample_audio = sr.AudioFile('sample.wav')
print("audio saved")

r = sr.Recognizer()
   
r.energy_threshold = 500  

   
with sample_audio as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, 0.25)
    audio = r.record(source)

key = r.recognize_google(audio)
   
print("key is : ", end="")
print(key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the sample.mp3 file in the working directory of the code?

Comment: I have sample.mp3 and the code on my desktop on both windows and raspberry pi 4

Comment: Is the sample.mp3 on the desktop itself or is it in the py_scripts folder?
if so try 'py_scripts/sample.mp3'

Maybe try using the absolute path to the sample.mp3 folder instead of the relative path (view the properties of the sample.mp3 folder and copy the location in front of sample.mp3)

Comment: sample.mp3 was on desktop and not in py_scripts. Thank you easy fix